# Add a tab to a Facebook page that allows users to post photos to already created albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photos

I am wondering if a tab in a Facebook Page can be created that would allow the users of the page to upload photos to the page's albums. I've looked everywhere for such solution, but I can not find it.

Does such ready solution exists? If now, can someone provide me with a ready solution for such functionality? I would be very grateful.

Regards,
Kiril

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Facebook Graph API to achieve this.

Familiarize with the following links, they will put you on the right track:

- http://developers.facebook.com/ (#1)
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (#5)
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (#4)
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ (#2)
- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk (#3)

The first thing you want to do is create an app (#1). Then you need to authorize the page you want to use with your app (#2; `offline_access, publish_stream` is what you are after). If you are developing using PHP then see #3 link. This will make things easier handling `signature_request`.

Assuming you want to create a form on a Page that will allow anyone to upload pictures to your Page. Create file upload form as usual. Once you have the file, initiate file upload to the Page gallery using Graph API (#4; http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). You also might want to authorize every user who uses your upload form, to distinguish uploaders.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Can someone provide me with an example of what should be created? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KirilIvanov No, example cannot be provided. This is not a spoonfeeding.com.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it myself.